# What version of JET does Windows Server 2003 ENT SP2 use?

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, jet

Normally when you look software on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) you can find information regarding the version numbers of a product and what the differences are between versions.

In the JET Wikipedia page I found the corresponding MS Access version and expected to find the corresponding JET engine version number...but it was not there, instead a there is dash!

[image: In the Wikipedia link above, the JET version number for MS Access 2003 is missing, it's just a dash...]

Scanning the text of the article a bit I find that:

> "Jet has been included in every version of Windows from Windows 2000 to
>   Windows 7...Access 2003 relied on the Jet
>   engine component of the operating system for its data storage and
>   query processing."
>    - [Wikipedia, Microsoft Jet Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine#History)

At this point I'm not certain if the versions of Windows 2000-7 includes the Windows Server versions as well.

And if it does include them, then what version of JET would MS Access use on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Msjet40.dll Jet 4.0 release level
version 
4.0.2927.4  Service Pack 3 (SP3)
4.0.3714.7  Service Pack 4 (SP4)
4.0.4431.1 or 
4.0.4431.3  Service Pack 5 (SP5)
4.0.6218.0  Service Pack 6 (SP6)
4.0.6807.0  Service Pack 6 (SP6) shipped only with Windows Server 2003
4.0.7328.0  Service Pack 7 (SP7)
4.0.8015.0  Service Pack 8 (SP8)
4.0.8618.0  Windows XP SP2 and Security Bulletin MS04-014
4.0.9025.0  Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Update Rollup 1 for Windows 2000 SP4
4.0.9505.0  Windows Server 2003 SP2
4.0.9511.0  Windows XP SP3 and Security Bulletin MS08-028
4.0.9635.0  Windows Vista
4.0.9704.0  Windows Vista   SP1 and Windows Server 2008
```

[How to determine the current release level of Jet 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)

Comment: Looking at the msjet40.dll I found, it says it is version 4.00.9505.0 which I am assuming to be the same thing as version 4.0.9505.0 in kb239114 above correct?  (why would they add an extra zero)?

Comment: Yes, these minor variations in numbering is normal.